# Closed formula for ${r \choose 1}+{r \choose 2}\cdots{r \choose w}$ where $w < r$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $r,w \in \mathbb{N}$. Are there some formula for the next sum?

$${r \choose 1}+{r \choose 2}\cdots{r \choose w}$$
where $w<r$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734900/proof-by-induction-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-sum-k-0n-n-k-2n , I think this is your question except they begin what you are calling w at.  Since the $0th$ zero of your sum would be 1 your sum is $2^r-1$.

Comment: @mikevandernaald thanks, by in my case $w<r$

Comment: No, doesnt exist closed formula for partial sums of binomial coefficients when the variable is $w$. But exist closed formula for some other cases, by example when the variable is $r$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form for this. See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n/17236). One answer rewrites the sum in terms of the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$.