# Demonstrate using the conditional expected value

Tags: probability

The joint probability function of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ is given by

$p(x,y)=\Biggl\{\frac 1{e^2y!(x-y)!}$ if $x=1,2...$ and $y=0,1,2,...,x$

and $p(x,y)=0$, $otherwise$.

Prove that $E[Y| X=x]=x/2$

I have doubts on how to attack this problem, I feel that it has to do something with the binomial variable, although I am not sure how to properly use the expected conditional value? Any contribution would be very helpful. Thanks, I'm new to the probabilities course!

Comment: $x=y$ is not allow in your definition!

Comment: @Maffred Sorry, I'm new to this topic, if you could guide me, it would be very helpful. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: I'm also not an expert in probability, but $p(x,x) = \infty$ which is not good. Are you sure $y$ can vary from $0$ to $x$? Are you sure this is a discrete probability and not a continuos one?

Comment: @Maffred I already edited the error in the denominator that caused the indetermination, I'm not sure if this distribution is discrete, it seems to be continuous.

Comment: It is discrete, as you define it only for integer numbers to be $\not = 0$.

Comment: I solved it I can't believe that xD

Comment: @Maffred You're right, but how does this help me see the conclusion I want to reach?

Comment: @Maffred It's good that you've solved it, I'm still stuck = (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bayes Formula tells us $$\mathbb P(Y=y|X=x) = \frac{\mathbb P(X=x,Y=y)}{\mathbb P(X=x)}.$$

We already have the numerator in the hypothesis. $$\mathbb P(X=x)= \sum_{y=0}^xp(x,y) = \frac{1}{x!e^2}\sum_{y=0}^x {x \choose y} = \frac{2^x}{x!e^2}.$$

Now $$\mathbb E(Y|X=x) = \sum_{y=0}^x yP(Y=y|X=x) = \frac{1}{2^x}\sum_{y=0}^x y{x \choose y} = \frac{1}{2^x}\cdot x \cdot 2^{x-1} = \frac x 2.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood, the main idea of the proof, but are there any additional details that you have used? Or did you only use the definition of conditional distribution?

Comment: I used the definition of conditional distribution and 2 identities involving binomial sums. Which part is not clear?

Comment: It would not be that we already have the denominator in the hypothesis? , what binomial identities did you use? because I see that that is the definition of combinatorial number in general.

Comment: I don't understand the first question. I made algebra tricks to let appear the needed parts of the definition of binomials in the sums. Then I used this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734900/proof-by-induction-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-sum-k-0n-n-k-2n and this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683733/sum-of-k-n-choose-k-is-n2n-1.

Comment: Thank you very much for attaching those links. In the first question, I meant that in your answer you wrote "We already have the numerator in the hypothesis". It would not be that we already have the denominator in the hypothesis?, sorry.

Comment: We know $p(x,y)$, which is $\mathbb P(X=x, Y=y)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything!, greetings from Venezuela.