# Series of binomial coefficient denominators

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, hypergeometric-function, beta-function

I'm not sure how to evaluate the following :

$$
\sum_{k=i}^n \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}
$$

Where $i,n \in \mathbb{N}, n > i$ are given.

I don't have any working for this, I just looked it at and don't have any idea how to go about evaluating it.

Comment: You can at most write it as $\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=i}^n\binom{n}{k}$ but there is no closed form for it.

Comment: You have one in the case $i = 0$.

Comment: @ncmathsadist I think for $i=0$ the sum is $\frac{2^n}{n!}$

Comment: @drhab - there may be a form related to the 
[regularized incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) though this is may not be helpful

Comment: @Henry I see. It somehow shifts from sums to integrals (which can always be labeled with some name).

Comment: WA gives the sum as $\frac1{n!}\,_2F_1(1,i-n;i+1;-1)$, where $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$ is the hypergeometric function. [(Link)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Fn!)*(sum%5Bn+choose+k,%7Bk,0,n%7D%5D-sum%5Bn+choose+k,%7Bk,0,i-1%7D%5D)) I've got a feeling you're unlikely to find any simpler representation of the formula than that, except for specific values of $n,i$.

Comment: Also, I'd note that expressing the sum in sigma notation, as a beta function or as a hypergeometric function may be redundant since it's just different ways of expressing the same thing without actually simplifying it.

Comment: Sorry there's a typo in my first comment, it should be $\frac{\binom{n}{i}}{n!}\,_2F_1(\ldots)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### No Closed Form

As pointed out by **@drhab**, your sum is equivalent to $\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=i}^n\binom{n}{k}$. Given that [$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734900/proof-by-induction-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-sum-k-0n-n-k-2n), your sum can be rearranged to $$\frac{2^n}{n!}-\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}\binom{n}{k}$$

Hence, the partial sum of binomial coefficients, $\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}\binom{n}{k}$, is the heart of your problem. The sum can be expressed in various other ways (such as with [hypergeometric](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5Bn+choose+k,%7Bk,0,i%7D%5D) or beta functions) and, as pointed out by **@Henry**, it has some nice expressions for specific $n,i$. But unfortunately, it has no closed form in terms of the sum of a fixed number of hypergeometric terms (Petrovsek, 1996. Theorem 5.6.3, pp. 88, 94, 102; **2**, p. 6). But then again, it could possibly have a different type of closed form.

#### References and Further Reading

Despite having no closed form, the sum has been studied before and can be approximated and bounded:

1. M. Petkovˇsek, G. S. Wilf and D. Zeilberger, 'A=B' (1996) [(purchase eBook)](https://www.crcpress.com/A--B/Petkovsek-Wilf-Zeilberger/p/book/9781568810638) [(PDF)](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.pdf)
2. M. Boardman, 'The Egg-Drop Numbers' (2004) [(link)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3219201?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
3. Bounds and algorithms. [(link)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n)
4. Approximations. [(link)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261428/approximation-of-sum-of-the-first-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n?noredirect=1&lq=1)
5. Asymptotics. [(link)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103280/asymptotics-for-a-partial-sum-of-binomial-coefficients)
6. Relation to hyperplanes. [(link)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258515/counting-regions-in-hyperplane-arranglements?noredirect=1&lq=1)
7. Wikipedia article. [(link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Partial_sums)