# How to prove $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}=2^n$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I need to prove this equality,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}=2^n$$

but I don't know how to start and what even to do

Comment: What does $C^i_n$ represent?

Comment: I'm assuming combination

Comment: @Javi: $C_n^i$ is a common notation for the binomial coeeficient.

Comment: You can make a proof by induction and use Pascal formula $C_{n}^i+C_{n}^{i+1}+C_{n+1}^{i+1}$

Comment: Does it work for $n=1$ ?

Comment: Please show me how to prove it... have no ideas

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734900/proof-by-induction-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-sum-k-0n-n-k-2n

Comment: See: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/CombinatorialProofs.shtml

Comment: @sam that is not *that* common a notation, though some calculators use $\;nCi\;$ or even $\;C^n_i\;$ (observe the order of the indexes)

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways to prove that, one already shown by the binomial theorem and the other by a **counting argument** that is:

- consider a set of $n$ elements and count the number of possible subsets of $k\le n$ elements we can choose among them, that is by definition

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk$$

- now since for each element we have two choice, to include or not include that in a given subset, by the [**Rule of product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)  the number of all possible subsets with $k\le n$ elements is given by

$$\overbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot \ldots \cdot 2}^{n \,elements}=2^n$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the binomial theorem:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k=(1+x)^n$$

putting $x = 1$,$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk=2^n$$

Think about the expansion of $(a+b)^n$

$$(a+b)^n = \binom{n}{0}a^n+\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b+...+\binom{n}{n-1}ab^{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}b^n $$

Now substitute $a = 1, b = 1$,

$$(1+1)^n = 2^n = \binom{n}{0}1^n+\binom{n}{1}1^{n-1}1+...+\binom{n}{n-1}1.1^{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}1^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$$

Hence,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$
which is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you!  what about if we expend given situation and take $(C_{n}^{k})^2$ instead $C_{n}^{k}$

Comment: Check out this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373122/sum-of-square-binomial-coefficients

Comment: can you explain me step by step?

Answer (score 0):

$$\Sigma_{i=0}^n C_i^n=C_0^n+C_1^n+C_2^n+C_3^n+...+C_n^n$$
 you expand using Binomial Theorem:$$(1+x)^n=C_0^n+C_1^n\cdot x+C_2^n\cdot x^2+C_3^n\cdot x^3+...+C_n^n\cdot x^n$$
On substituting $x=1$:
$$(1+1)^n=C_0^n+C_1^n\cdot 1+C_2^n\cdot 1^2+C_3^n\cdot 1^3+...+C_n^n\cdot 1^n$$
Or, $$2^n=C_0^n+C_1^n+C_2^n+C_3^n+...+C_n^n=\Sigma_{i=0}^n C_i^n$$

> $$\Sigma_{i=0}^n C_i^n=2^n$$